# Checking user access permissions to a virtual path in medium trust

Tags: c#, httpmodule, medium-trust

If I wanted to check whether the current user has access to a given url in full trust I can use code like this.

```cs
IPrincipal user = context.User
                ?? new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(
                                        string.Empty, 
                                        string.Empty), 
                   new string[0]);

UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(virtualPath, user, "GET");
```

Unfortunately this does not work in a medium trust environment as the `CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal` method has the following flags.

```cs
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Unrestricted=true)]
```

Is there a way I can check whether the virtual path user permission in a medium trust? I'm rewriting a path in a HttpModules `PostAuthorizeRequest` event handler so I need to be able to check permissions after the rewrite.